Connection forcibly closed by remote host
I'm trying to publish a Blazor Web APP .NET 8 application developed on VS 17.9.2 on a company hosted server via IIS. However every time, the publication fails with the following error:

Retrying the 'Serialization' operation on the sitemanifest (sourcePath) object. Attempt 2 of 50. (and so on until 50 tries)
Added file ({sitename}/{appName}\wwwroot_content\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication\AuthenticationService.js).
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.200\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\targets\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(140,5): Warning: Retrying synchronization following a socket error (10054).

I can't really get a clue of what the inner error might be, I checked user permissions and folder permissions but everything seems fine. Do you have any idea?
I know similar question had already been asked but I'm not using any Azure Services to accomplish my objective that's why I opened a new issue regarding it, my colleague is able to publish whatever he wants, although this is the first .NET 8 app we want to publish so maybe my problem is coming from it and I want to read fresh answers not aged ones. Thanks in advance
